# Ubuntu 18.10 gnome extensions stop working after hibernation

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, 18.10

After upgrading to 18.10 I am experiencing very strange behaviour of gnome extensions. After my laptop goes into hibernation they all switch off and enabling them back on https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ doesn't help: nothing changes and when I refresh the page they are disabled again.

The only way to turn them back on is to reinstall them.

Answer (score 8):

As per GNOME's security policy, whenever you *hibernate* or *suspend* or even *lock your screen*, *all* of your extensions get disabled automatically until you get back in, and only then the extensions get re-enabled. It seems in your case somehow the re-enabling process is not getting executed properly. This should be considered a bug, consider reporting at launchpad.net.

Also as a workaround after getting back from hibernation / suspension / lock-screen, restart GNOME shell once by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then typing `r`, and finally pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the extensions should start work again.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions about what to try to reinstall?

Comment: @EgorIgnatenkov Bugs like [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1236749) pop up every now and then, not sure what's causing the issue in your case.  Consider reporting a bug against the `gnome-shell` package at launchpad.net.

Comment: On my 18.10 laptop `ALT+F2 r` doesn't restart the extensions, I have to bring up GNOME tweaks and re-enable them from there.  Didn't use to be an issue before the 18.10 upgrade (ie worked fine on 18.04).  What's peculiar is that the Ubuntu dock extension does appear to re-enable itself ok

Comment: @pomsky: sorry should have mentioned: X.org

Comment: I am facing this issue of gnome extensions turning off after waking from sleep on Ubuntu 18.04 too (noticed since past 1-2 weeks). ```Alt+F2``` then ```r``` solved my issue.

Comment: Can confirm this new and very annoying behaviour on 18.04. It's even happening after locking/unlocking the screen. On 18.10 it seems to be fixed since about the same time it occured on 18.04. :|