# Missing app-indicator icons in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: icons, indicator, gnome-shell

After unlocking my computer, I noticed that all of my usual indicator icons went missing this afternoon. I'm missing icons for Slack, Keybase, Chrome, Nextcloud Client, Dropbox, Deluge, Flameshot, and Skype. Before I noticed this, I also noticed that my side-bar (with icons for my open apps and favorited ones) was visible on my lock-screen. I couldn't get a screenshot of that, though, as the Print Screen was (rightfully) still disabled on lock screen and is probably not related.

[image]

I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079510/missing-indicator-tray-icons-steam-chrome-dropbox-etc), but his issue was that Unity was messing him up. This particular laptop has never had anything below 18.04 installed on it. It came with Windows 10 but I promptly replaced it with Ubuntu 18.04 as soon as I got it. As such, Unity has never been installed.

Comment: One-time issue or happening all the time?

Comment: @pomsky This is the first time I've noticed it after about 9 months of owning the laptop. I did run an `apt full-upgrade` today, but it only installed updates to Libre Office and DBeaver.

Comment: This glitch happens every now and the, kinda hard to reproduce. See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087051/ubuntu-18-10-gnome-extensions-stop-working-after-hibernation

Comment: try restarting that some times helps for me

Comment: @pomsky thanks for the tip. I never use sleep or hibernate, this happens after just a simple lock. Hopefully they'll get this fixed soon enough.

Comment: Locking screen is enough to hit this wall as due to GNOME's security policy, whenever you even lock your screen, *all* of your extensions get disabled automatically until you get back in. It seems the re-enabling process for the appindicator extension fails sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and running <kbd>r</kbd> will reset the indicator icons and get them to show again. More information and a permanent fix can be found here, [Fix Missing Indicator Icons On Ubuntu 18.04 Or 18.10](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/fix-missing-indicator-icons-in-ubuntu.html) . I too have experienced this issue on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install. I haven't yet tried the permanent fix as listed in the website I linked.

Comment: works fixed all my issues was not aware of that alt + f2 command stuff amazing thanks a lot using ubuntu 21